# Make Div Slide in from right to left when scrolling down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that fades in while  I scroll down the page and fades out when I scroll up the page. I would like to make it slide in from right to left when I scroll down and slide from right to left when i scroll up.

Below is the code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 200) {
$('.header-avail').fadeIn();
} else {
$('.header-avail').fadeOut();
}
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgLL8e77/)

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mgLL8e77/3/) something like what you're searching for?

Comment: @G.Hunt no more like the whole div that is next to the sliding div should move

Comment: There is no div next to the red one? There's just that `<li>` element in your fiddle.